# saving pdf plots in a specific file in r

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I have created multiple plots that are saved in a list. 
Now I want to save them keeping the name they have on the list. 
My code until now is as follows.

```
 pdfplots <- function(PlotList){
 L <- List()
    for (i in 1:length(L)){
    names(L[[i]]) <- paste0(names(PlotList), i)
    pdfPath <- (file = "~/Documents/MyFile/MyPlots, names(L[[i]])")
    myplot <- boxplot(PlotList[[i]]) 
 }
 dev.off()
 }
```

As a result I want to get a pdf plot saved on a specific path. 
Any help will be deeply apreciated

Comment: 1. in `pdfPath` line, quotes are in wrong places. 2. `pdf()` command is missing. 3. Use `lapply` to loop through a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `pdf` function. The chunk below should be doing the job:

```
    pdfplots <- function(PlotList){
            for (i in 1:length(PlotList)){
            fullFileName = paste0("~/Documents/MyFile/MyPlots/", names(PlotList)[i],".pdf")
            pdf(fullFileName)
            boxplot(PlotList[[i]]) 
            dev.off()
            }
}
```